# How do I access the transferred contents from a cross-domain getScript() AJAX request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, getscript

I am using the jQuery (1.7.2) getScript() AJAX method to fetch an external (cross-domain) HTML page which contains embedded javascript.  I am using the 'script' data type for the getScript() command because it has no cross-domain restrictions.  In the browser's JS console, I use the following code which is equivalent to a getScript() request:

```
$.ajax({
    url:    url,    // This url is for an HTML page with embedded JS - not for a JS file
    type:           'get',
    crossDomain:    true,
    dataType:       'script',
    beforeSend: function(result) { result.setRequestHeader('Accept', '*/*') },
    success:    function(result) { console.log('SUCCESS:\t' + result) },
    error:      function(result) { console.log('ERROR') },
    complete:   function(result) { console.log('COMPLETE:\t' + result.responseText) }
})
```

This returns with 'success', but no result.

```
SUCCESS:    undefined
COMPLETE:   undefined
```

The console also tells me that the content was interpreted as a script but transferred with MIME type text/html (I suppose this is because the url I'm using is for an HTML page).  I know the entire HTML data was transferred to the client because I can access it using the browser JS console's network panel, and I can confirm that the correct number of KBs was indeed transferred.

I'm not sure I'm concerned about the MIME message because I really just need to get my hands on the transferred content and do some parsing.  How can I access this transferred content - which is somewhere on the client side - using jQ/JS?  If I can't get to it, how is it that the browser console's network panel has access to it?

Comment: Why are you using `dataType: 'script'` for something which isn't a script?

Comment: Because this dataType (and 'jsonp') are not subject to the "same-origin" restriction for get().  Also - in the browser JS console - this command actually retrieves the remote HTML content, with the embedded script that I need.  I just don't know how to get to the transferred content.

Comment: By the way, the same request with dataType: 'jsonp' returns with error, whereas the 'script' request returns with success.

Comment: Any reason you can't use an iFrame?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't get to the content, otherwise it would be extremely easy to make cross-domain requests and cross-domain requests wouldn't be an issue. If you are using the script datatype, the response must be a script. if you are using the jsonp datatype, the response must be valid JSONP.

Comment: @MichaelMior: Re: Using an iFrame, I need the returned data textually in order to parse it - I don't need to present it in a webpage.

Comment: @KevinB: It seems that way doesn't it?  I'm resigning to this reality unless someone comes through with a technique that has eluded us...